# search for a string in a list based on a hierarchy

Tags: c#, .net, vba, algorithm

I have a predetermined hierarchy of strings and would like to return the string which is ranked higher in the hierarchy, some of the strings are sub-strings of another string. For e.g. "abb" and "abb be"

**Hierarchy** - abc de, abb be, ccdd, aab, abb, aabb, abc, ccde

I would like to output the string based on the order in the hierarchy

**Input** - abb, aabb, ccdd
**Output** - *ccdd*
For the above example, the output should be *ccdd* as it is listed before *aab* and *aabb* in the hierarchy

Here is one more example -

**Input** - abc, aabb, ccde
**Output** - *aabb*
Here the output should be *aabb* as it is listed before *abc* and *ccde* in the hierarchy

What is the best way to solving such a problem?

Comment: First I don't see any hierarchy, but simply a list of strings, so it sounds like ordering by the index from another list problem. Second, why the second example does not return *ccdd* as well (it's before *abc* and *aabb*)?

Comment: agree with Ivan, i would return ccdd in the second example too

Comment: Which language are you trying to use to solve this problem?  The "best way" could be very different in C# than what it would be in VBA!

Comment: @IvanStoev I updated the question, ccdd was a misprint. The order listed in the hierarchy list reflects the hierarchy

Comment: @YowE3K I included VBA and C# both as I can implement the solution in both languages, Just looking for how to approach such a problem

Comment: So the problem can be defined as: find the input element with minimum index from the predefined list. You can approach it in many ways, including simple `for` loop in case the input is relatively small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most efficient way in C# would be to convert the input to a `HashSet`, then use either forward loop or LINQ on the predefined list and return the first matching element.

For instance:

```
var ordered = new List<string> { "abc de", "abb be", "ccdd", "aab", "abb", "aabb", "abc", "ccde" };
var input = new List<string> { "abb", "aabb", "ccdd" };
// LINQ solution
var result = ordered.FirstOrDefault(new HashSet<string>(input).Contains);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could on every input go through the rank list to determine the rank, but i would first convert rank list to a Dictionary. After that you could just order your input on rank and take first one:

```
var rank = new List<string> { "abc de", "abb be", "ccdd", "aab", "abb", "aabb", "abc" };
var rankDict = rank.Select((i, s) => new { i, s }).ToDictionary(x => x.i, x => x.s);

var input = new List<string> { "abb", "aabb", "ccdd" };

var result = input.OrderBy(s => rankDict[s]).FirstOrDefault();
```

If not all strings from the input are presented in the rank list, you could rank them with lowest priority:

```
var result = input.OrderBy(s => rankDict.ContainsKey(s)?rankDict[s]:Int32.MaxValue).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim arrOrder, arrTest, m

arrOrder = Array("abc de", "abb be", "ccdd", "aab", "abb", "aabb", "abc")

arrTest = Array("abb", "aabb", "ccdd")

m = Application.Evaluate("=MIN(IFERROR(MATCH({""" & Join(arrTest, """,""") & """}," & _
            "{""" & Join(arrOrder, """,""") & """},0),999999))")

Debug.Print arrTest(m - 1)
```